# Shorthand Javascript code to set all keys in an array to empty ("") strings

Tags: javascript

I have an array as shown in my code below. How would I reset all these strings to "", without actually having to explicitly refer to each key? Is there any way I can just refer to the parent object and say that all its children = ""?

```
rmtData = {
  FirstName : "Jane",
  LastName  : "Doe",
  Gender    : "F",
  Details   : "Therapist"
};

//other code here...

//then reset all variables here:

rmtData.FirstName = "";
rmtData.LastName  = "";
rmtData.Gender    = "";
rmtData.Details   = "";
```

Comment: Ah right. Thanks Yeah.

Comment: [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I have to ask - "why?".  It appears to be an unusual requirement, normally one would just start with another blank object.

Comment: Its 3-way bound with an angularFire $firebaseArray object service. If I start with a new array, the bindings are lost and a second set of operations on those variables don't seem to recognize the keys anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var key in rmtData ) rmtData[key] = "";
```

and yes, it is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 3):

You can get keys of object with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function and then iterate it:

```
Object.keys(rmtData).forEach(function(key) {
    rmtData[key] = "";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a function to do that..
It looks like you have an object to use n times so I would do something like this

```
function new_rmtData(){ 
    var xxx = {
    FirstName: "",
    LastName : "",
    Gender : "",
    Details : ""};
    return xxx;
}
```

so every time you need to set a new var or to reset one you have just to call the function..

```
rmtData = new_rmtData();
```

Comment: Ah I see, yeah should work too. I'll experiment with that option haha